# Class constructor with default parameters

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I the next simple constructor:

```
Vector(double x=0, double y=0) : x(x), y(y) {}

void operator+=(const Vector& other) {
    this->x += other.x;
    this->y += other.y;
}
```

But when I call it like this

```
Vector b();
Vector a(1,1);
```

and try to do a += b;
compiler gives me a lot of errors saying that no operators exist. However when I do like this:
Vector b(0,0); 
or 
Vector b(0);
everything works(((

Comment: Why would you think that such a constructor would enable usage of `+=`? If you want the operator, you have to overload it. That has nothing to do with constructors. But as a side note, you should make this constructor explicit, or simple numbers will implicitly convert to vectors as x coordinates.

Comment: I have an operator. Now I add it...

Comment: btw, `this->` is not necessary

Comment: @RobertMutke I do like to use `this` in such cases to be clear which of the two objects is being used.

Comment: @NeilKirk kinda matter of taste, but still should be rather avoided http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337540/when-should-you-use-the-this-keyword-in-c

Comment: You know, you really, really want to mark that ctor `explicit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Vector b();` doesn't create an object. It declares a function.

```
Vector b;
Vector a(1,1);
```

should work.