# Use of "this" keyword in C++

Tags: c++, this

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is excessive use of this in C++ a code smell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057425/is-excessive-use-of-this-in-c-a-code-smell)
>   [When should you use the "this" keyword in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337540/when-should-you-use-the-this-keyword-in-c-closed)
>   [Is there any reason to use this->](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577243/is-there-any-reason-to-use-this)

In C++, is the keyword `this` usually omitted? For example:

```
Person::Person(int age) {
    _age = age;
}
```

As opposed to:

```
Person::Person(int age) {
    this->_age = age;
}
```

Comment: most people use it when the variable passed to the function has the same name as the instance variable...

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Yes, it is not required and is usually omitted. It might be required for accessing variables after they have been overridden in the scope though:

```
Person::Person() {
    int age;
    this->age = 1;
}
```

Also, this:

```
Person::Person(int _age) {
    age = _age;
}
```

It is pretty bad style; if you need an initializer with the same name use this notation:

```
Person::Person(int age) : age(age) {}
```

More info here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: I have no idea what the last syntax is called, could you give me some hint / info about what to search for to understand how does that work ?

Comment: @Stormsson [Member initializer lists.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Comment: It's not just bad style, it's also less efficient than initialization. Moreover, const and reference variables must be initialized on the line they are declared.

Comment: @orlp there is actually a case where you have to use `this->` pointer: if you are using derived template classes. In the first compilation phase, the member variables of parent-classes need to be accessed with `this->` or `ParentClass::` to make sure the compiler knows that those are not typenames.

Answer (score 35):

It's programmer preference.  Personally, I love using `this` since it explicitly marks the object members.  Of course the `_` does the same thing (only when you follow the convention)

Comment: The underscore only does the same thing if you follow the convention.

Comment: Using `this` to explicitly mark object members also only works when you follow the convention.

Comment: Note that "the convention" @Rich has mentioned is to use an underscore prefix to indicate object members. When you do not follow the convention, the method parameter has exactly the the same name as the object member, and `this` is required to avoid ambiguity. But I believe an explicit `this` "works" whether or not you follow the convention.

Answer (score 14):

Either way works, but many places have coding standards in place that will guide the developer one way or the other.  If such a policy is not in place, just follow your heart.  One thing, though, it REALLY helps the readability of the code if you do use it. especially if you are not following a naming convention on class-level variable names.

Answer (score 7):

`this` points to the object in whose member function it is reffered, so it is optional.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. unless, there is an ambiguity.

Comment: `o avoid some compilers optimizing virtual function call`, How so?

Comment: I am also keen on knowing the answer to that. @AlokSave maybe you now know and are willing to share?

Comment: I don't remember exactly right now. But adding 'this' was required in some special case due to some compiler bug when I wrote the answer 9 years ago. Probably it is fixed now. Removed from answer.

Answer (score 3):

For the example case above, it is usually omitted, yes.  However, either way is syntactically correct.